# Mouseonclick show/hide divs imagemap? [Jquery/css]

Tags: jquery, show-hide, imagemap, onmouseover

I've been looking at a bunch of different questions and answers here regarding a project I have to do. I'm still unsure of the best way to go about it.

At this point I have a large image with one part of the image to be cut up into 5 uneven parts. Each part/section is a category. When it is clicked the color of the section changes and some images and text should be displayed to the right of the image in a separate div. I'm pretty much a newbie to jquery but I have a background in js and css.

I'm unsure if highlighting of the sections (onmouseover) of the image will be needed. But would love that possibility as well.

I want to know if an image map or pagx,pagey coordinates for the onclick events should be used? Also, how can I replace the section with the highlighted version?

I guess I would like to replace the section with another image that shows the user that he clicked on that section.

I would prefer not to use a plugin just straight coding.

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): _You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page._ **You can visit:** [http://www.learningjquery.com/](http://www.learningjquery.com/) and [http://jquery.com/](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: It's a valid question - image map vs pagex pagey coordinates. Plus overwriting an imagemap with another image.

Comment: It is a bit open-ended which I believe is what @Zuul was explaining.  Perhaps you can put some more detail about the image and sections.  Maybe even attempt something and edit the question with some code you've tried, so we can better understand your problem.  It will be easier to help with something more clear and direct.

Comment: The problem is, as stated on the FAQ, that you have not posted any code to your problem, you are trying to obtain either a working solution or the research for a procedure that you intend achieve! For that, is commonly used a search engine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really are stuck on how to start coding something like described on your question, I believe that no answer will ever be good enough, but to point you on some path (right or not):

Here a working example of a [Imagemap rollover using jQuery](http://www.svennerberg.com/2008/09/imagemap-rollover/).

**Also:**

Another tutorial on how to build a [interactive image map with Jquery!](http://www.gethifi.com/blog/jquery-vs-flash-for-interactive-map)

Those two provide you with a starting point to what you are describing!

Best of luck to your work!

Comment: http://www.svennerberg.com/2008/09/imagemap-rollover/ The first link is dead here is the correct link

Comment: For some reason I thought I couldn't vote - your first link helped me tremendously thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You really should provide some code, but I think image maps are better solution. [Here](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-toolbar/toolbar.php?wptbto=http://abhinavsingh.com/webdemos/indiaimagemap/&wptbhash=aHR0cDovL2FiaGluYXZzaW5naC5jb20vYmxvZy8yMDA5LzAzL3VzaW5nLWltYWdlLW1hcHMtaW4tamF2YXNjcmlwdC1hLWRlbW8tYXBwbGljYXRpb24vPHdwdGI%2bVXNpbmcgSW1hZ2UgTWFwcyBpbiBKYXZhc2NyaXB0ICYjODIxMTsgQSBEZW1vIEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uPHdwdGI%2baHR0cDovL2FiaGluYXZzaW5naC5jb20vYmxvZzx3cHRiPkFiaGkmIzAzOTtzIFdlYmxvZw==) is  demo of image map. Give it a look and you will see if this solution is for you.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like something I could use!